# Where is the default index.html.erb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, config

I'm following the setup instructions here http://railsinstaller.org/mac and when I get to step 8 where I'm asked to edit the welcome index.html which can be found under app/views/welcome/index.html.erb I go to app/views and there's no welcome folder.

The only thing I can think of is in step 6 where I'm asked to visit the command line prompt and create a welcome controller for the index action, but when I enter

```
$ rails g controller welcome index
```

into a new terminal window I get a whole bunch of commands I can use but can't find where to create the welcome folder and the index.html.erb.

Maybe I should just make a folder and create a index.html.erb file to put in it, but where would I find such a file?

Comment: You're right, that's the step when the index.html.erb file will be generated. When you opened the terminal window, did you `cd` into the correct directory? What was the output from the `rails generate` command?

Comment: When I enter rails generate into a terminal window I get too much data to be able to enter in this comment box.

All I know for sure is that everything is running in a folder on my desktop called railsinstaller_osx_demo

Comment: When I run the generate command above, I get 16 lines of output. Do you get more than that? Are there any errors? There should be a line like: `create    app/views/welcome/index.html.erb`.

Comment: OK I got it, cd into the views folder then ran

    rails g controller welcome index

thanks - I'd forgotten all about cd - this is going to be lots of coffee time coming up.

Comment: Hmm, you should be fine to run it in the same folder as where you ran `rails new`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by rails_new but no doubt I'll figure it out when I'm making more progress. Obviously the step by step instructions assume I know about cd - that might explain why Step 5 didn't work either - setting up a symlink to subl. They assumed I placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, which I did, but I  didn't have a ~/bin directory in the path, and I still don't, so was unable to to run:

     ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl

Comment: The "rails new xxx" command is in step three in the tutorial you linked to. Good luck!

Comment: Yep, it's all coming together now. Your cd comment opened the floodgates. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

you could simply add it under the `app/view` folder ,it's okay...

well, don't forget to rm the index page under the `public` folder

Answer (score 1):

I opened a new terminal window and used cd to get to the root of the railsinstaller_osx_demo folder on my desktop and then entered `rails g controller welcome index`

This created the welcome folder and the index.html.erb file.

Thanks to [Douglas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119271/douglas) for suggesting "When you opened the terminal window, did you cd into the correct directory?".

Also thanks to everyone else, all answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The Home page is at:

> app/views/static_pages/home.html.erb

Answer (score -1):

By default rails will create the standard html file ie **index.html** file which is in the public folder. And it will consider it for the root_url.Please check in the 'config/routes.rb'.
  **root :to => 'welcome#index'**

If you want the default root_url to be changed, you need to remove the **index.html** file in the public folder, and change the root_url according to your wish.